# Write values based on a array to a certain cell across worksheets Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign a list of names to a certain cell (E4) across all worksheets. This is what I have so far. I am not sure the proper way of assigning values from a array across all worksheets. The error message says the subscription is out of range. But I can't find a solution to fix it. Thank you

```
Sub test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim i As as Long
Dim myArray As Variant
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet9")
myArray = Worksheets("data").Range("range")
 With ws
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range(i, 4) = myArray(i)
    Next
  
 End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myArray` is a one-based, 2D array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("range")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(myArray, 1) to UBound(myArray, 1)
         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("E4").Value = myArray(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

This assumes that `Worksheets.Count <= UBound(myArray, 1)`, i.e. `Range("range")` has as many rows (or more) as the number of worksheets.

Comment: When I ran the code, it assigns values from "range" to each worksheets. Is there a way to assign one value at a time (A1 to E1 in Sheet 1, A2 to E1 in sheet2, etc.) Thank you

Comment: Check the edited code I posted (you may have to refresh the page).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have several issues including incorrect loop structure, the way you are using the 'With' statement, and incorrect assignment of the array value to the cell. This should work as expected.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myArray As Variant
    
    myArray = Worksheets("data").Range("A1:A10").Value ' Assuming data is in A1:A10 in "data" sheet
    
    For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "data" Then ' Skip the data sheet
                ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = myArray(i, 1) ' Assuming you want to write to column E (5)
            End If
        Next ws
    Next i
End Sub
```

- To assign one value at a time from the array to corresponding worksheets, you can use a counter variable to move through the array as you loop through the worksheets.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myArray As Variant
    
    myArray = Worksheets("data").Range("A1:A10").Value ' Replace A1:A10 with your actual range
    i = 1
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "data" And i <= UBound(myArray, 1) Then
            ws.Cells(1, 5).Value = myArray(i, 1) ' Write to E1 in each sheet
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `ws.Cells(i, 5)` is E1, not E4.

Comment: Ahhh! You are correct.

Comment: When I ran the code, it assigns values (A1:A10) to each worksheets. Is there a way to assign one value at a time (A1 to E1 in Sheet 1, A2 to E1 in sheet2, etc.) Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This is also a great way to solve my problem. I will save your answer.